# Post to Google+ communities not showing publicly or other members, only to me

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-communities

I joined few communities related to my niche and started posting there today.
But I noticed that on the community page, the post shows only to me and not to the public or other members.

Only in one community did the post become publicly visible and I got traffic.

What is the reason for my post not showing up?

Comment: I may have found a solution (however I am not able to post my answer).

If you go to this URL: https://plus.google.com/settings/audience - there is an option under "Global settings" called "Who can view my content" - I had mine set to 'No one'.

I have just changed it to Anyone.

Answer (score 2):

Google+ communities have their own policies or customs on what is allowed to be posted in their groups. You may have been seen as a spammer, as you mention posting to a few different communities after joining, and the moderators would have deleted such posts.

If you can see the post on your own profile, but it is not showing up in the community you posted it, check for a strike-out or line-through at the name of the group and the category.

For example:

[image: deleted google+ post]

This was posted to a group, but was deleted by the moderator. It still shows up on the user's own view of their posts.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you post frequently, for a while your posts might stop becoming visible to others. I have tried several ways but this issue is solved on its own after sometime.

Comment: After sometime means how much time?

Answer (score 0):

My posts don't show up to anybody else unless I tag them, but only if they're shared to a community.

Every single community I post in does things this way.